# Getting Run time Error 13- VBA excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

[image] Hi I am having a excel file. There is a macro in the excel file to clear the dependent drop down list . When we copy the value from one row to another row or one column to another column we are getting run time error 13. Could you please help us to resolve the issue

Code :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
           If Target.Row > 2 And Target.Row < 100 Then

   If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Target.Value = "Create Account_Personal" Then   
    Target.Offset(0, 3).Value = "NA"
   Target.Offset(0, 4).Value = "NA"
   Target.Offset(0, 5).Value = "NA"
   Target.Offset(0, 6).Value = "NA"
   Target.Offset(0, 7).Value = "NA"
   Target.Offset(0, 8).Value = "NA"
   Target.Offset(0, 9).Value = "NA"
   Target.Offset(0, 10).Value = "NA"
   Target.Offset(0, 11).Value = "NA"
     Target.Offset(0, 19).Value = "NO"
   Target.Offset(0, 22).Value = "NO THANKS"

      ElseIf Target.Column = 2 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Target.Value <> "Create Account_Personal" Then
      Target.Offset(0, 3).Value = "Select Country"

End If
   If Target.Column = 5 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Target.Value <> "NA" Then
   Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = "select State"
   Target.Offset(0, 2).Value = ""
   Target.Offset(0, 3).Value = ""
   Target.Offset(0, 4).Value = ""
   Target.Offset(0, 5).Value = ""
   Target.Offset(0, 6).Value = ""
   Target.Offset(0, 7).Value = ""
   Target.Offset(0, 9).Value = ""
   Target.Offset(0, 10).Value = ""
   Target.Offset(0, 11).Value = ""
   Target.Offset(0, 12).Value = ""
   Target.Offset(0, 13).Value = ""
   Target.Offset(0, 14).Value = ""
   Target.Offset(0, 15).Value = ""
  End If

End If
End Sub`enter code here`
```

[image]

Comment: Press debug when error arises and paste the screenshot so we can understand better what’s happening

Comment: @RicardoDiaz No screenshots of code or errors please read [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: @Vijayakumar Please [edit] your question and tell us in which line of code the error occurs (after you pressed the "Debug" button).

Comment: Just checking you know it's `ByVal` - not `By Val` ?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ You’re right. Just to see what line. OP posted the code already.

Comment: @RicardoDiaz What I meant is we don't need an image to see which line it is, he just needs to tell us in which line the error occurs.

Comment: When i clcik the debug button i am getting the error in the below line If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Target.Value = "CreateAccount_Personal" Then

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Disable events by using `Application.EnableEvents = False`
2. For consecutive cells use  …

   ```
   Target.Parent.Range(Target.Offset(0, 3), Target.Offset(0, 11)).Value = "NA"
   ```

   … to write  `NA` between column 3 and 11. Which is much shorter and faster.

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo ENABLE_EVENTS

    If Target.Row > 2 And Target.Row < 100 Then
        If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
            If Target.Value = "Create Account_Personal" Then
                Target.Parent.Range(Target.Offset(0, 3), Target.Offset(0, 11)).Value = "NA"
                Target.Offset(0, 19).Value = "NO"
                Target.Offset(0, 22).Value = "NO THANKS"
            ElseIf Target.Value <> "Create Account_Personal" Then
                Target.Offset(0, 3).Value = "Select Country"
            End If
        End If

        If Target.Column = 5 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
            If Target.Value <> "NA" Then
                Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = "select State"
                Target.Parent.Range(Target.Offset(0, 2), Target.Offset(0, 7)).Value = ""
                Target.Parent.Range(Target.Offset(0, 9), Target.Offset(0, 15)).Value = ""
            End If
        End If
    End If

ENABLE_EVENTS:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting  runtime error 13 in the below line If Err.Number <> 0 Then Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext

Comment: @Vijayakumarj See my edited answer. This will fix it.

Comment: Hi PEH ,Thank you so much. It is working  without showing any error. Thanks a lot again . May i know what is the issue with earlier code

Comment: The issue is that if `Target` is more than one cell then `Target.Value` returns an array of values and `If Target.Cells.Count = 1 And Target.Value = "Create Account_Personal"` fails because the second part of the `And` is tested even if the first part is `false`.

Comment: Hi PEH, I got it . Thank you for clarifying and fixing the issue

Comment: Hi PEH , I am having 3 columns A,B,C if column A and B is yes then I have to change column c is correct . could you please help me how we can check 2 columns at a time. when I am using below stmt i am not able to do it If Target.Row > 2 And Target.Row < 100 Then
If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then  if Target.value="YES"then
If Target.Column = 3 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then if Target.value="YES" then Target.offset(0,1).value="c" End if End if End if End if